# Can you use a promise as input for an assert?

Tags: node.js, selenium, promise, assert, newrelic

I'm currently writing synthetic browser monitor scripts and am seeing a lot of failures due to timeouts -- specifically when looking for an html ID.

```
assert.ok($browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.id("framedContent"), 5000))
```

`$browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.id("framedContent"), 5000)` is a promise that waits before looking for the ID "framedContent". I'm wondering if it's plausible that the **assert.ok** isn't "smart" enough to wait for the promise to fulfill, even though it technically can take a promise as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `assert.ok` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_ok_value_message) declare that `assert.ok` just tests for truthiness. All Promise objects are truthy, resolved or not, because all Javascript objects are truthy. Aside from that, `assert.ok` is synchronous and couldn't react to an asynchronous Promise's result anyway.

You might reach for [`assert.doesNotReject`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_doesnotreject_asyncfn_error_message), which *does* accept a Promise and *does* wait for the result, but it also behaves asynchronously and returns a Promise. This won't be better than your bare call to `waitForAndFindElement`, as described in the docs:

> Using `assert.doesNotReject()` is actually not useful because there is little benefit in catching a rejection and then rejecting it again. Instead, consider adding a comment next to the specific code path that should not reject and keep error messages as expressive as possible.

For that reason, you may need to `await` your `waitForAndFindElement` in order to turn it into the kind of error that will actually (appropriately) wait for your element to appear or make your test fail otherwise.